Dynamic Allocation cannot apply for executor because the pendingTask variable in driver has become negative
In certain specific situations, such as after canceling a stage, dynamic allocation may result in a negative calculation of the required number of executors, causing new queries to be unable to apply for any executors. I have placed the environment configuration at the end of this article.
When the following error log appears, submitting another query with a total task<=2 will not trigger the request executor.
2024-09-12 16:19:30 DEBUG ExecutorAllocationManager:64 - max needed for rpId: 0 numpending: -2, tasksperexecutor: 3
2024-09-12 16:19:30 DEBUG ExecutorAllocationManager:64 - No change in number of executors

Then I added detailed logs in a function maxNumExecutorsNeededPerResourceProfile in core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ExecutorAllocationManager.scala.
    logInfo(s"max needed for rpId: $rpId numpending: $numRunningOrPendingTasks," +
      s" tasksperexecutor: $tasksPerExecutor, pendingTask: $pendingTask," +
      s" pendingSpeculative: $pendingSpeculative, unschedulableTaskSets: $unschedulableTaskSets," +
      s" running: $running")

The negative number comes from the pendingTask variable like this log below.
2024-09-19 16:30:10 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - max needed for rpId: 0 numpending: 1192, tasksperexecutor: 3, pendingTask: -1, pendingSpeculative: 0, unschedulableTaskSets: 0, running: 1193

After adding some INFO log and reviewing ExecutorAllocationManager's log, I found that onTaskStart still starts after onTageComplete end.
2024-10-12 13:20:41 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - ExecutorAllocationManager.onStageCompleted lock end: stageId: 197, stageAttemptId: 0,stageAttemptToNumTasks: Map(),stageAttemptToPendingSpeculativeTasks: Map(),stageAttemptToTaskIndices: Map(),stageAttemptToSpeculativeTaskIndices: Map(),stageAttemptToExecutorPlacementHints: Map(),stageAttempt: Stage 197 (Attempt 0)
2024-10-12 13:20:41 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - onStageCompleted allocationManager.onSchedulerQueueEmpty()
2024-10-12 13:20:41 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - Clearing timer to add executors because there are no more pending tasks
2024-10-12 13:20:41 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - [onTaskStart] taskIndex: 11374 lock start, stageAttemptToTaskIndices: 0
2024-10-12 13:20:41 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - stageAttemptToTaskIndices size + 1
2024-10-12 13:20:41 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - ExecutorAllocationManager.getPendingTaskSum: numTotalTasks = 0, numRunning = 1 stageAttemptToNumTasks = Map()

But onStageComplete will remove (stage-> taskNum) in stageAttemptToNumTasks and stageAttemptToTaskIndices, then onTaskStart insert a new  (stage-> [taskIndex]) into stageAttemptToTaskIndices.
    override def onStageCompleted(stageCompleted: SparkListenerStageCompleted): Unit = {
      val stageId = stageCompleted.stageInfo.stageId
      val stageAttemptId = stageCompleted.stageInfo.attemptNumber()
      val stageAttempt = StageAttempt(stageId, stageAttemptId)
      allocationManager.synchronized {
        // do NOT remove stageAttempt from stageAttemptToNumRunningTask
        // because the attempt may still have running tasks,
        // even after another attempt for the stage is submitted.
        stageAttemptToNumTasks -= stageAttempt
        stageAttemptToPendingSpeculativeTasks -= stageAttempt
        stageAttemptToTaskIndices -= stageAttempt
        stageAttemptToSpeculativeTaskIndices -= stageAttempt
        stageAttemptToExecutorPlacementHints -= stageAttempt
        removeStageFromResourceProfileIfUnused(stageAttempt)

        // Update the executor placement hints
        updateExecutorPlacementHints()

        // If this is the last stage with pending tasks, mark the scheduler queue as empty
        // This is needed in case the stage is aborted for any reason
        if (stageAttemptToNumTasks.isEmpty
          && stageAttemptToPendingSpeculativeTasks.isEmpty
          && stageAttemptToSpeculativeTaskIndices.isEmpty) {
          allocationManager.onSchedulerQueueEmpty()
        }
      }
    }

    override def onTaskStart(taskStart: SparkListenerTaskStart): Unit = {
      val stageId = taskStart.stageId
      val stageAttemptId = taskStart.stageAttemptId
      val stageAttempt = StageAttempt(stageId, stageAttemptId)
      val taskIndex = taskStart.taskInfo.index
      allocationManager.synchronized {
        stageAttemptToNumRunningTask(stageAttempt) =
          stageAttemptToNumRunningTask.getOrElse(stageAttempt, 0) + 1
        // If this is the last pending task, mark the scheduler queue as empty
        if (taskStart.taskInfo.speculative) {
          stageAttemptToSpeculativeTaskIndices.getOrElseUpdate(stageAttempt,
            new mutable.HashSet[Int]) += taskIndex
          stageAttemptToPendingSpeculativeTasks
            .get(stageAttempt).foreach(_.remove(taskIndex))
        } else {
          stageAttemptToTaskIndices.getOrElseUpdate(stageAttempt,
            new mutable.HashSet[Int]) += taskIndex
        }
        if (!hasPendingTasks) {
          allocationManager.onSchedulerQueueEmpty()
        }
      }
    }

Then getPendingTaskSum got the negative pending task number,  it affected the requesting of executors.
    private def getPendingTaskSum(attempt: StageAttempt): Int = {
      val numTotalTasks = stageAttemptToNumTasks.getOrElse(attempt, 0) // get 0
      val numRunning = stageAttemptToTaskIndices.get(attempt).map(_.size).getOrElse(0) // get postitive number
      numTotalTasks - numRunning // get negative number
    }


Another Complete Case Info After Modified Some Func Code
Temporarily added some correction operations to getPendingTaskSum function.
    private def getPendingTaskSum(attempt: StageAttempt): Int = {
      val numTotalTasks = stageAttemptToNumTasks.getOrElse(attempt, 0)
      val numRunning = stageAttemptToTaskIndices.get(attempt).map(_.size).getOrElse(0)
      if (numTotalTasks == 0) {
        if (numRunning > 0) {
          logInfo(s"ExecutorAllocationManager.getPendingTaskSum: numTotalTasks = 0, " +
            s"numRunning = $numRunning, return the corrected 0")
        }
        return 0
      }
      logInfo(s"ExecutorAllocationManager.getPendingTaskSum: numTotalTasks = $numTotalTasks," +
        s" numRunning = $numRunning stageAttemptToNumTasks = $stageAttemptToNumTasks")
      numTotalTasks - numRunning
    }

    override def onTaskStart(taskStart: SparkListenerTaskStart): Unit = {
      val stageId = taskStart.stageId
      val stageAttemptId = taskStart.stageAttemptId
      val stageAttempt = StageAttempt(stageId, stageAttemptId)
      val taskIndex = taskStart.taskInfo.index
      allocationManager.synchronized {
        logInfo(s"[onTaskStart] taskIndex: $taskIndex lock start, " +
          s"stageAttemptToTaskIndices: ${stageAttemptToTaskIndices.size}")
        stageAttemptToNumRunningTask(stageAttempt) =
          stageAttemptToNumRunningTask.getOrElse(stageAttempt, 0) + 1
        // If this is the last pending task, mark the scheduler queue as empty
        if (taskStart.taskInfo.speculative) {
          stageAttemptToSpeculativeTaskIndices.getOrElseUpdate(stageAttempt,
            new mutable.HashSet[Int]) += taskIndex
          stageAttemptToPendingSpeculativeTasks
            .get(stageAttempt).foreach(_.remove(taskIndex))
        } else {
          stageAttemptToTaskIndices.getOrElseUpdate(stageAttempt,
            new mutable.HashSet[Int]) += taskIndex
          logInfo(s"stageAttemptToTaskIndices size + 1")
        }
        if (!hasPendingTasks) {
          logInfo(s"onTaskStart allocationManager.onSchedulerQueueEmpty()")
          allocationManager.onSchedulerQueueEmpty()
        }
        logInfo(s"[onTaskStart] taskIndex: $taskIndex lock end, " +
          s"stageAttemptToTaskIndices: ${stageAttemptToTaskIndices.size}")
      }
    }

    override def onStageCompleted(stageCompleted: SparkListenerStageCompleted): Unit = {
      val stageId = stageCompleted.stageInfo.stageId
      val stageAttemptId = stageCompleted.stageInfo.attemptNumber()
      val stageAttempt = StageAttempt(stageId, stageAttemptId)
      allocationManager.synchronized {
        // do NOT remove stageAttempt from stageAttemptToNumRunningTask
        // because the attempt may still have running tasks,
        // even after another attempt for the stage is submitted.
        logInfo(s"ExecutorAllocationManager.onStageCompleted before: " +
          s"stageId: $stageId, stageAttemptId: $stageAttemptId," +
          s"stageAttemptToNumTasks: $stageAttemptToNumTasks," +
          s"stageAttemptToPendingSpeculativeTasks: $stageAttemptToPendingSpeculativeTasks," +
          s"stageAttemptToTaskIndices: $stageAttemptToTaskIndices," +
          s"stageAttemptToSpeculativeTaskIndices: $stageAttemptToSpeculativeTaskIndices," +
          s"stageAttemptToExecutorPlacementHints: $stageAttemptToExecutorPlacementHints," +
          s"stageAttempt: $stageAttempt")
        stageAttemptToNumTasks -= stageAttempt
        stageAttemptToPendingSpeculativeTasks -= stageAttempt
        stageAttemptToTaskIndices -= stageAttempt
        stageAttemptToSpeculativeTaskIndices -= stageAttempt
        stageAttemptToExecutorPlacementHints -= stageAttempt

        logInfo(s"ExecutorAllocationManager.onStageCompleted after: " +
          s"stageId: $stageId, stageAttemptId: $stageAttemptId," +
          s"stageAttemptToNumTasks: $stageAttemptToNumTasks," +
          s"stageAttemptToPendingSpeculativeTasks: $stageAttemptToPendingSpeculativeTasks," +
          s"stageAttemptToTaskIndices: $stageAttemptToTaskIndices," +
          s"stageAttemptToSpeculativeTaskIndices: $stageAttemptToSpeculativeTaskIndices," +
          s"stageAttemptToExecutorPlacementHints: $stageAttemptToExecutorPlacementHints," +
          s"stageAttempt: $stageAttempt")
        removeStageFromResourceProfileIfUnused(stageAttempt)

        // Update the executor placement hints
        updateExecutorPlacementHints()

        // If this is the last stage with pending tasks, mark the scheduler queue as empty
        // This is needed in case the stage is aborted for any reason
        if (stageAttemptToNumTasks.isEmpty
          && stageAttemptToPendingSpeculativeTasks.isEmpty
          && stageAttemptToSpeculativeTaskIndices.isEmpty) {
          logInfo(s"onStageCompleted allocationManager.onSchedulerQueueEmpty()")
          allocationManager.onSchedulerQueueEmpty()
        }
      }
    }

2024-10-14 15:48:44 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - ExecutorAllocationManager.onStageCompleted after: stageId: 244, stageAttemptId: 0,stageAttemptToNumTasks: Map(),stageAttemptToPendingSpeculativeTasks: Map(),stageAttemptToTaskIndices: Map(),stageAttemptToSpeculativeTaskIndices: Map(),stageAttemptToExecutorPlacementHints: Map(),stageAttempt: Stage 244 (Attempt 0)
2024-10-14 15:48:44 INFO  TaskSetManager:60 - Finished task 675.0 in stage 244.0 (TID 449322) in 1876 ms on jp02-ime-uts3-hdp682.jp02.baidu.com (executor 3452) (1738/7350)
2024-10-14 15:48:44 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - onStageCompleted allocationManager.onSchedulerQueueEmpty()
2024-10-14 15:48:44 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - Clearing timer to add executors because there are no more pending tasks
2024-10-14 15:48:44 INFO  TaskSetManager:60 - Finished task 2138.0 in stage 244.0 (TID 450610) in 606 ms on jp02-ime-uts3-hdp682.jp02.baidu.com (executor 3452) (1739/7350)
2024-10-14 15:48:44 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - [onTaskEnd] taskIndex: 26 lock end, stageAttemptToTaskIndices: 0
2024-10-14 15:48:44 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - [onTaskStart] taskIndex: 7298 lock start, stageAttemptToTaskIndices: 0
2024-10-14 15:48:44 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - stageAttemptToTaskIndices size + 1
2024-10-14 15:48:44 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:60 - ExecutorAllocationManager.getPendingTaskSum: numTotalTasks = 0, numRunning = 1, return the corrected 0

stage 244 status

task 7298 status


Env:

Spark 3.4.2

Spark Conf
spark.ui.port 8057
spark.master yarn
spark.submit.deployMode cluster
spark.executor.instances 0
spark.executor.cores 3
spark.executor.memory 12g
spark.memory.fraction 0.8
spark.executor.pyspark.memory 0m
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled: true
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout 60
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors 0
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors 400
spark.port.maxRetries 300
spark.shuffle.service.enabled true
spark.driver.cores 10
spark.driver.memory 10g
spark.sql.hive.filesourcePartitionFileCacheSize 1073741824
spark.speculation true
spark.speculation.interval 1s
spark.speculation.multiplier 3
spark.sql.adaptive.enabled true
spark.sql.optimizer.insertRepartitionBeforeWrite.enabled true
spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes 32m
spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.minPartitionNum 1
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version 2
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions 800
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold 100m
spark.sql.adaptive.forceOptimizeSkewedJoin true
spark.shuffle.file.buffer 32m
spark.shuffle.unsafe.file.output.buffer 32m
spark.reducer.maxSizeInFlight 128m
spark.hadoop.dfs.client.hedged.read.threadpool.size 3
spark.hadoop.dfs.client.hedged.read.threshold.millis 3000
spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.executorManagement.capacity 20000

Is there any version that fixes this issue?
